# Using HTMLUnit to get javascript elements

Tags: html, xml-parsing, html-parsing, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HTMLUnit to get the javascript elements on a webpage (https://www.coursera.org/courses), and it is only loading the html data. How do I get it to display the information shown in the javascript container?

Thanks!

My current code:

```
     public String DownloadPage(String str){
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(20000);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    try{
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(str);
        XmlPage page2 = webClient.getPage(str);
        int n = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100000); 

        System.out.println("Executing " + n + " JavaSript jobs!"); 
        System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + page2); 

        System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + page.asXml()); 
        webClient.closeAllWindows(); 
    }

    catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
    }


    webClient.closeAllWindows();
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String theContent1 = webClient.getPage(theURL).getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

instead of

```
String theContent2 = webClient.getPage(theURL);
```

theContent1 should contain the actual page source including JavaScripts (if any).